# xslt - merge grandchild nodes into parent container

Tags: xml, xslt, grandchild

I have an XML structure as such:

```
  <GetAccount_Output>
     <GetAccountResponse>
        <AccountCollection>
           <Account>
              <AccountId>1</AccountId>
           </Account>
        </AccountCollection>
     </GetAccountResponse>
     <GetAccountResponse>
        <AccountCollection>
           <Account>
              <AccountId>2</AccountId>
           </Account>
        </AccountCollection>
     </GetAccountResponse>
  </GetAccount_Output>
```

The desired output is:

```
        <GetAccount_Output>
           <GetAccountResponse>
              <AccountCollection>
                 <Account>
                    <AccountId>1</AccountId>
                 </Account>
                 <Account>
                    <AccountId>2</AccountId>
                 </Account>
              </AccountCollection>
           </GetAccountResponse>
        </GetAccount_Output>
```

I can manage to remove one:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:copy>
      <GetAccountResponse>
        <xsl:copy-of select="GetAccountResponse/*"/>
      </GetAccountResponse>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name()!='GetAccountResponse']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Giving this result:

```
        <GetAccount_Output>
           <AccountCollection>
              <Account>
                 <AccountId>1</AccountId>
              </Account>
              <Account>
                 <AccountId>2</AccountId>
              </Account>
           </AccountCollection>
        </GetAccount_Output>
```

But I don't know how I can merge both `GetAccountResponse` and `AccountCollection`?
Anyone who can push me towards the correct solution?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to look at it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="GetAccount_Output">
    <GetAccount_Output>
        <GetAccountResponse>
            <AccountCollection>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="GetAccountResponse"/>
            </AccountCollection>
        </GetAccountResponse>
    </GetAccount_Output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="GetAccountResponse">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="AccountCollection/Account"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

--
Here's another:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <GetAccount_Output>
        <GetAccountResponse>
            <AccountCollection>
                <xsl:for-each select="GetAccount_Output/GetAccountResponse/AccountCollection/Account">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </AccountCollection>
        </GetAccountResponse>
    </GetAccount_Output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Dang, I was just starting to write essentially the same answer when you posted... :)  +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different way of doing it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Copy all nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Ignore any GetAccountResponse except the first -->
    <xsl:template match="GetAccountResponse[position() != 1]"/>

    <!-- Include all Account in AccountCollection -->
    <xsl:template match="AccountCollection">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//Account"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```